# Angular form validation: compare two fields

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular-forms, angular-validation

In an Angular 4 application, how can I validate two fields of a form doing a comparison?

For example, let's suppose that my form has a `startDate` and an `endDate` date fields and I want to make sure that the `endDate` must be bigger than the `startDate`.

Comment: Have you tried accessing two values on the form by [(ngModel)] and then compare two values?

Comment: @ShinDarth below my answer help you ???

Comment: @Robert thanks for your answer however I used amal's solution which looks more straightforward

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you want to implement validations containing one or more sibling (form)controls, you have to define the validator function on a level up/above that of the sibling controls. For ex:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
        'startDate': ['', [<control-specific - validations >]],
        'endDate': ['', [<control-specific - validations >]]
    }, { validator: checkIfEndDateAfterStartDate });
}
```

Then outside the component class's definition (in the same file), define the function `checkIfEndDateAfterStartDate` as well.

```
export function checkIfEndDateAfterStartDate (c: AbstractControl) {
    //safety check
    if (!c.get('startDate').value || !c.get('endDate').value) { return null }
    // carry out the actual date checks here for is-endDate-after-startDate
    // if valid, return null,
    // if invalid, return an error object (any arbitrary name), like, return { invalidEndDate: true }
    // make sure it always returns a 'null' for valid or non-relevant cases, and a 'non-null' object for when an error should be raised on the formGroup
}
```

This validation will make the `FormGroup` invalid by adding the error-flag (here `invalidEndDate`) to `true` to the errors object for that `FormGroup`. If you want to have specific errors to be set on any of the sibling controls instead, then you can manually set the error flags on that `formControl` by using something like, `c.get('endDate').setErrors({ invalidEndDate: true })`. If you do this, then make sure you clear them for a valid case by setting the errors to `null` like this, `c.get('endDate').setErrors(null)`.

A live demo of a similar validation can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/xYv9lsrV0s4?t=14m15s).

Comment: I don't think you need to export the check function. Also why have you declared `c` as `AbstractControl` and not just `FormGroup` ?

Comment: Yes, you don't necessarily have to 'export' the function if it is in the same file. I declared it as an `AbstractControl` since it is the base class for `FormGroup`s (and also for `FormControl`s and `FormArray`s). No harm in doing that. Also helps you use all the properties defined in that class 'typescript'-ically.

Comment: @ShinDarth Can you please post you code .html with .ts ? i'm fascing the same situation  . thank's in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export class validationComponent implements OnInit {
     private testForm:FormGroup;

     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

     }

     ngOnInit() {
         this.testForm = this.fb.group({
           'startDate': ['', [Validators.required]],
           'endDate': ['', [Validators.required]]
        });

       this.subscribeDateChanges();
    }

    subscribeDateChanges() {
        const startDateChanges = (<any>this.testForm).controls.startDate.valueChanges;
        const endDateChanges = (<any>this.testForm).controls.endDate.valueChanges;

        startDateChanges.subscribe(start => {
             this.testForm.controls['endDate'].
               setValidators(
                [Validators.required,
                CustomValidators.minDate(this.toYYYYMMDD(start))]);
        this.validateDates();
       });

       endDateChanges.subscribe(end => {
               this.validateDates();
         });
     }

   dateError: boolean = false;
   validateDates(): void{
       let startDate = this.testForm.controls['startDate'].value;
       let endDate = this.testForm.controls['endDate'].value;
       if(endDate && startDate){
           this.dateError = endDate <= startDate;
        }
    }

   toYYYYMMDD(d:Date): string {
       d = new Date(d)
       var yyyy = d.getFullYear().toString();
       var mm = (d.getMonth() + 101).toString().slice(-2);
       var dd = (d.getDate() + 100).toString().slice(-2);
       return yyyy + '-' +  mm + '-'  + dd;
   }
```

based on the **dateError** boolean value you show error msg