# Angular 2 field a dependency on field b

Tags: angular

I have two fields A. Min as text box B. Max as a textbox
When the form loads i have min as O.3 and max as 0.5

Both the fields are required.

So if u change the field min as 0.8 ,the error shows up as min should be less than max , till that moment the field will be shown as red border since it is wrong.
When i go and change my max as 0.9 the red border should automatically disappear, since technically now min is less than max.
So the change of one field Should validate another field.

I want to handle this in angular 2.

I tried doing it using onchange and other waya it did not work.
And when i write onchange function in html file
I want to get group = control.parent in my ts file 
(Which is a form in angular )

Which i am not able to get.

Can somebody has solution to this in angular 2?

Comment: check this bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181312/angular-form-validation-compare-two-fields

Comment: Thats a little different this is different , try it !